# How to remove or uninstall a Unity scope

Tags: uninstall, unity-dash, lenses, scopes, removing

I intalled the Unity Photo Lens using this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-photo unity-scope-flickr unity-scope-shotwell
```

And then downloading and executing a deb package found [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webapps_preview/precise/main/base/unity-lens-photo). Flickr scope works fine. However, the Shotwell scope is not working and has caused errors in my system. The question is how can I remove or uninstall the Shotwell scope or any scope without affecting others scopes or lenses? Thanks!

Comment: It's always a good practice to note down links to blog posts according to which you install scopes. This way you won't be guessing on the scopes package names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the package `unity-scope-shotwell`, for example using

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-scope-shotwell
```

and then log in again.